# Is there a backstab animation in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am just wondering if in Skyrim there is a backstab animation, when using a small blade and sneaking behind an opponent, much like the regular slo mo animations that occur when getting a critical hit kill?

(is this a slash to the throat? simple backstab? does this differ and occur on human/monster targets?)

Comment: there are multiple backstab animations, including the slash to the throat and a stab to the back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they do have a animation. Look [HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYnJmN0dLf4) for a video on how to perform a backstab.
No perks are needed to perform the backstab animations, just that you need to perform enough damage for a 1 hit kill from stealth.

The official strategy guide confirms that they are random, and that they do no extra damage: they're pure aesthetics. It suggests that you can increase your chances by executing a power attack on the last enemy in a group.

Hope this helped, cheers marco

Comment: no perks are needed to perform the backstab animations, just that you need to perform enough damage for a 1 hit kill from stealth.